# Javascript in html, variable doesn't seem to be usable

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get the variable for year working,I tried this and it should work. I am new to JS and HTML please forgive the naive questions

HTML page that includes a simple form. ask the visitor to type in his/her 
name, and year he/she was born. Write a JavaScript to extract the data from the form when 
the submit button is clicked. The script should display the following information in a new 
document. 
Hello, Visitor’s name, you are xx years old. (Your script should show an error message if a 
visitor type in a future year.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>

 <form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" id="FirstName" ><br>
 Birth year: <input type="integer" id="BirthYear" ><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick = "test1();">
</form>

    <script>
     var curYear = today.getFullYear(); 

  function test1(){

var yy = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var xx = document.getElementById("BirthYear").value;

if( xx < curYear){
xx = curYear - xx;
    document.write("Hello," + yy + ", you are " +  xx  + " years old");

}
else{
alert("Your age is invalid");
}
}



    </script>


    </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the variable `today`. Add `var today = new Date();` before the `var curYear = today.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't instantiated `today`:

```
var today = new Date();              // add this line
var curYear = today.getFullYear();   // now `today` will resolve
```